# Infinite Recursion, StackOverError in huffman tree

Tags: java, encoding, recursion, huffman-code

I am working on a Huffman Encoding program and I am almost finished but I am stuck in an infinite recursion loop.  Does anyone have an idea where this is going wrong?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.nio.cs.SingleByteEncoder.encodeLoop(SingleByteEncoder.java:130)
at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:544)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:252)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:476)
at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:619)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:756)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:63)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
at HuffmanNode.buildTree(hw4.java:64)
```

and the output is continually 5:1, 5:4, 5:2, repeating

my datafile looks like this:

```
a
a
a
a
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
d
k
k
k
k
k
k
f
f
f
f
f
f
h
h
h
h
h
h
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
b
n
n
n
n
n
n
n
e
e
e
e
e
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
i
l
k
j
a
n
s
g
l
k
j
a
s
v
o
i
j
a
s
d
l
k
g
k
n
m
a
s
d
k
l
o
v
h
a
s
d
g
z
```

and my code is

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class HuffmanNode implements Comparable<HuffmanNode>{
HuffmanNode right;
HuffmanNode left;
HuffmanNode parent;
int count;          
String letter;

public HuffmanNode(){}

public HuffmanNode (String letter, int count){
this.letter = letter;
this.count = count;
}
public HuffmanNode (String letter, int count, HuffmanNode parent, HuffmanNode left, HuffmanNode right){
    this.letter = letter;
    this.count = count;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
    this.parent = parent;
}

public void setCount(int count){
this.count = count;
}

public int getCount(){
return count;
}

public void setRight(HuffmanNode right){
this.right = right;
}

public HuffmanNode getRight(HuffmanNode right){
return right;
}

public void setLeft(HuffmanNode left){
this.left = left;
}

public HuffmanNode getLeft(HuffmanNode left){
return left;
}       
public void setParent(HuffmanNode right){
this.left = left;
}   
public HuffmanNode getParent(HuffmanNode parent){
return parent;
}

public void buildTree(HuffmanNode node){
    if (node.compareTo(this) <= 0 && left != null){
    System.out.println(node.getCount() + ":" + this.count);
    left.buildTree(node);
    }
    else if (node.compareTo(this) <= 0 && left == null){
    this.left = node;
    node.parent = this;
    }
    else if (node.compareTo(this) > 0 && right != null){
    System.out.println(node.getCount() + ":" +this.count);
    right.buildTree(node);
    }
    else if (node.compareTo(this) > 0 && right == null){
    this.right = node;
    node.parent = this;
    }
}


public int compareTo(HuffmanNode x){
return this.count - x.count;
}
public void genCode(String s){
    if(left != null){
    left.genCode(s + "0");
    }
    if(right != null){
    right.genCode(s + "1"); 
    }
    if (left == null && right == null){
    System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}

public class hw4{
public static void main (String []args)throws IOException{

//ask user to enter file name
System.out.printf("Enter a file location and name to encode [press Enter]: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String filename = input.next();

//Gets file name from Scanner and checks to see if valid
File file = new File(filename);
//if (!file.isFile()){
//System.out.printf("Enter a file location and name to encode [press Enter]: ");
//}
Scanner text = new Scanner(file);

String[] letters = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
int[] freq = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

String letter;
String tempStr;
int tempInt;

    while(text.hasNext()){
        letter = text.next();
        //System.out.printf("%s\n", letter);

                    char c = letter.charAt(0);
        int index = c - 97;
        freq[index]++;     
    }

    for(int i=0; i <25; i++){
    System.out.printf("%s:%d\n", letters[i], freq[i]);
    }
    System.out.printf("\n");

    for (int n=0; n <25; n++) {
        for (int i=0; i <25; i++) {
            if (freq[i] > freq[i+1]) {
                // exchange elements
                tempInt = freq[i];  
                tempStr = letters[i]; 
                freq[i] = freq[i+1];
                letters[i] = letters[i+1];  
                freq[i+1] = tempInt;
                letters[i+1] = tempStr;
            }
        }   
       } 

    PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode> huffmanList = new PriorityQueue<HuffmanNode>();

    for(int i=0; i <26; i++){
    System.out.printf("%s:%d\n", letters[i], freq[i]);
        if(freq[i] > 0){
        huffmanList.add(new HuffmanNode(letters[i],freq[i]));
        }
    }

    HuffmanNode root = new HuffmanNode();

    while(huffmanList.size() > 1){
    HuffmanNode x = huffmanList.poll();
    HuffmanNode y = huffmanList.poll();
    HuffmanNode result = new HuffmanNode("-", x.getCount() + y.getCount(), null, x, y);
        if(root == null){
        root = result;
        }
        else{
        root.buildTree(result); 
        }
    huffmanList.add(result);                    
    }
     root.genCode(" ");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tree-building is at fault.

```
while(huffmanList.size() > 1){
    HuffmanNode x = huffmanList.poll();
    HuffmanNode y = huffmanList.poll();
```

You take the two lightest trees from the queue,

```
    HuffmanNode result = new HuffmanNode("-", x.getCount() + y.getCount(), null, x, y);
```

and merge them, forming a tree with the sum of weights as weight - so far, so good.

```
    if(root == null){     // never happens, but doesn't matter
        root = result;
    }
    else{
        root.buildTree(result);
```

Then you insert the new-formed tree into the `root`,

```
    }
    huffmanList.add(result);                    
}
```

and add it back into the queue.

Now, let us consider a queue starting with

```
(a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,3), (e,3), ...
```

`root = new HuffmanNode();` set `root` to `(null, 0)`.

First, the `a` and `b` nodes are merged, giving `<(a,1) | (-,3) | (b,2)>`. Inserting into `root` produces

```
         (null,0)
          /    \
        null  (-,3)
              /   \
            (a,1) (b,2)
```

since `3 > 0`. The queue is

```
<(a,1) | (-,3) | (b,2)>, (c,3), (d,3), (e,3) ...
```

after inserting the merged tree [the merged tree could also be inserted after a couple of weight-3 nodes, then it would take a bit longer].

Now the two lightest trees are popped and merged, giving

```
<AB | (-,6) | (c,3)>
```

(with the abbreviation `AB = <(a,1) | (-,3) | (b,2)>`). That tree is then inserted into the `root` tree. `6 > 0`, so it's inserted into the right child of `root`, `6 > 3`, so it's inserted into the right child of `(-,3)`, `6 > 2`, so it becomes the right child of the `(b,2)` node. But, the left child of the newly merged tree and the right child of `root` refer to the same object, so after this insertion, you have

```
                   __________
                  |          |
                  v          |
    (null,0)   (-,6)         |
    /      \   /   \         |
  null     (-,3)   (c,3)     |
           /   \             |
       (a,1)   (b,2)         |
                   \_________|
```

a cycle in what's supposed to be a tree. Next, the two nodes `(d,3)` and `(e,3)` are popped and merged, giving a tree of weight 6, and when that tree shall be inserted into the `root` graph, it would loop.

Different insertion behaviour and/or different weights of the letters would change the details, but the fact that after `root.buildTree(result);` and `huffmanList.add(result);` the queue contains a reference into the graph topped by `root` leads to cycles whenever you have enough nodes initially. And once you have enough cycles, the probability that a `buildTree()` call will not land in an infinite loop is small.

You simply should not call `root.buildTree(result)`. The tree is constructed by simply merging the two lightest from the queue and reinserting the result, until the queue contains only one tree.

```
while(huffmanList.size() > 1){
    HuffmanNode x = huffmanList.poll();
    HuffmanNode y = huffmanList.poll();
    HuffmanNode result = new HuffmanNode("-", x.getCount() + y.getCount(), null, x, y);
    huffmanList.add(result);                    
}
root = huffmanList.poll();
```

Comment: Dan. A truely spectacular and intuitive answer.  My greatest thanks to you for spending the time to diagnose the code in such a diligent manner. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if(root.equals("null")){
```

to

```
if(root == null){
```

Also

try to shorten your numerious `if` code like this

```
 char c = letter.charAt(0);
 int index = c - 97;
 freq[index]++;
```

Comment: @user1093111, ok, by you have to change it anaway. Comparing reference with String makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Ill check it in a moment. I tried makin it a string because i got an error that said it was not comparable. Undo til i can get to that point when i get out of class, and fix the freq if statements

Comment: Very bizarre, I pasted and it works very well? What code do you have in line ?

Comment: @Dimitri. What do you mean in line

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov k I did the edits, how ever still have the error

Comment: @user1093111 I mean in line 63